# Need Help: carousel not rotating to next slide - new and stumped

Tags: carousel

First time updating this website and unsure how to activate the carousel... currently it just stays on the first image and won't rotate to the next slide.

I have confirmed the image file names and paths are correct. Any insights or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Had to Screenshot the code because the portion `<ol class="carousel-indicators"....` disappears when entering in post body on stackflow... weird... maybe an indication that is the problem area?

[See Screenshot of Coding Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLjVG.png)

```
 <!-- Header Carousel -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
 $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000
})

<!-- Indicators -->

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>         
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides (v2/legends_treasures.html) -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
                 <a href="">
              <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('https://guernseys.com/Guernseys%20New/images/1900x1080artauction.jpg');"></div> 
                  </a>
        </div>      

        <div class="item active">
                 <a href="">
              <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('https://guernseys.com/Guernseys%20New/images/1900x1080henrymiller.jpg');"></div> 
                  </a>
        </div>      
    </div>

 <!-- Controls -->

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
   
</header>
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Stackflow won't allow me to enter the patch of code... Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: What do you mean by "below"? I can't see any markup in your code. Also, please add proper tags for the technologies that are relevant

Comment: Can you view the image from the link in the original post?

Comment: If that image contains code, share it as such - in text form

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you for helping, I was getting an error when trying to add the code which is why I shared the image before... now i've updated question with chunk of code.  If you need the whole page code let me know and I can update that if possible.